# Why does a broken image shows up even database is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, web

So I am trying to get the photo from the database whenever the user uploaded one. But in my case, even though the user didn't upload a photo nor do not have a a photo saved in the database, a broken image still shows up. I do not know what's wrong with my code but I hope you guys can help me.

Here's my news.php code:

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("alumni") or die(mysql_error());

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC"); 

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo ['title'];
    $img = ['photo'];
    if($img != ""){
      $photo = '/alumni/news/'.$img;
    echo "<img name='" . $photo . "' src='" . $photo . "' width='750' height='300' alt='img1'/>";
    }           
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo ['body'];
    echo "<br><br>Posted at ";
    $row_date = strtotime($row['date']);
    echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $row_date);
}?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$img` is an empty string if no image exists? Are you trying to check `$img['photo']` ?

Comment: Hi sir @HebleV , i did posted my entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the array in the line `$img = ['photo'];`. With this instruction you create an array with one element with the value `'photo'`, so it `$img` is always different than `""`. The instruction should be `$img = $row['photo'];`

Comment: Oh, thank you sir David. My mistake was the `$img = ['photo'];` Now it's working. Yay!  :)

Comment: Sorry, in the first post it was wrong, but after the last edit it is ok. I have updated my answer.